# How to logout to the same URL from where it has been login in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am logging in from one site and going into the second site. when i logout from the second site how do i return back to the same first site from where i have logged into the second site. can any one help me in this....

I am trying to get the $sername=$_SERVER['REMOTE_live_site']; remote live site i.e first site live site value at the place whwre the logout button is used. but there i am not bale to get the first site live_site value.. how can i do this...

Comment: post your tried code for it...

Answer (score 0):

Just set the return url in your form as a hidden varibale.

like below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode('full logout url');?>" />
```

Hope its works..

Comment: Does the URL not have to have a domain? Will it not work with the domain? I feel like if you need to switch to a different site, you will need to set the domain.

Comment: @DavidFritsch for logout to different site should be with domain. I didn't noticed thanks.. Iam not sure its works with domain on same site.